# MGTwitterEngine statusesReceived not firing

Tags: ios, twitter, mgtwitterengine

A few time ago I've developed an iOS app with MGTwitterEngine and XML parsing option.

Since Twitter updated the API to 1.1, seems to be that all messages must be called with JSON format.

After a long nightmare to integrate YAJL library with MGTwitterEngine, my program makes a Succeeded Request but the statusesReceived delegate method is not fired.

I've checked if the delegated is properly assigned, and everything is correct. After launch the HTTP request I get the response OK but not any message.

Here an example of the call I made:

```
INFO -> Twitter URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?since_id=1&screen_name=CFarmaceutico&count=50
```

And here the response:

```
MGTwitterEngine: (200) [no error]:
{
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 10778;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 28 Nov 2013 11:57:33 GMT";
    Expires = "Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Thu, 28 Nov 2013 11:57:33 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = tfe;
    "Set-Cookie" = "lang=es, guest_id=v1%3A138563985309026395; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 28-Nov-2015 11:57:33 UTC";
    Status = "200 OK";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=631138519";
    "x-access-level" = "read-write-directmessages";
    "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "x-rate-limit-limit" = 180;
    "x-rate-limit-remaining" = 166;
    "x-rate-limit-reset" = 1385639983;
    "x-transaction" = da0b638eef7ffe43;
    "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
}
2013-11-28 12:57:34.025 Otsuka On[60073:a0b] Request Suceeded: 59CA5086-8AA9-4632-978B-2B9F2334D704
```

But the statusesReceived method is not called anymore.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

no idea - but MGTwitterEngine does not support API 1.1, and when API 1.1 was released, we tried hard to get MGTwitterEngine working - and failed. Eventually we converted our app to [FHSTwitterEngine](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine) - and it works fine since then. It was relatively straightforward process so I would strongly recommend you to do the same. It will take you less time than fixing bugs in MGTwitterEngine.